# Using Jsoup CSS selector for the text between 2 elements

Tags: html, css, jsoup

all. I'm using jsoup css seletor for web page scraping, but don't know how to get the text between 2 tags. as shown below:

`<html>` 
`<body>`

`<a` name = "xxx" `>` some text here`</a>`

`<a` name = "abc"`>` the text 1 `</a`>`

i wanna get the text here

`<a` name = "cde"`>`the text 1 `</a>`

```
</body>
</html>
```

the attribute name of `<a>` is unique on the hmtl

I found most answers were to extract the text between `<a>` `</a>`

anyone know how to do this. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

OK I made this little code it work for me

```
String html = "<html> <body><a name = xxx > some text here</a><a name = abc> the text 1 </a>i wanna get the text here<a name = cde>the text 1 </a></body></html>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    String body = doc.body().toString();
    String[] a = body.split("</a>");
    String lista = a[2];
    String[] listb = lista.split("<");      
    String textBetweenA = listb[0];
    System.out.println(textBetweenA);
```

Comment: @aeTechMoy, it doesn't work. please check my html source updated. before the tag <a>, no any element contain the tag <a>.